# How to Tell VS 2012 to Finish Debugging Session and Skip Remaining Breakpoints

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

I'm debugging a program using Visual Studio 2012. It goes through the same functions multiple times using different parameters. As I learn more information from the debugging session sometimes I want to start over, but with the architecture we are using it would be easier to just finish running the piece of code it is going through than to stop the session and start again. But because it goes through the same functions repeatedly it keeps stopping at my breakpoints.

Is there a way to tell Visual Studio to finish running and ignore all remaining breakpoints without removing them for the next time I go through the code, and without stopping the debug session? I've tried to search for information on this but I didn't see anything.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the breakpoints window (debug/windows/breakpoints) there is a button to enable/disable all breakpoints.

Comment: There isn't one but if you use it often you can assign one yourself. Also you can select it from the quick launch, ctrl+q and then start typing "disable all breakpoints"

Comment: Thank you. That was super helpful. For anyone else reading this, you can set your own breakpoints in VS 2012 by going to Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard.